# Plotting with plotnine opens many windows

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pycharm, plotnine

I am using [plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to plot graphics. plotnine uses Qt. When I plot the first graphic, e.g. with

```
import pandas as pd
measurements = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0,1], 'value': [2,3]})
import plotnine as p
p.ggplot(p.aes('time', 'value'), measurements) + p.geom_line()
```

I get the plot just fine. But when I execute another Python command (not necessarily a plot, but not for every command - I was not able to determine what kind of command), I am getting

```
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

and I new matplotlib windows open. This happens until my console crashes. What is going on?

Also, when I command the plot, I get a second window which is just black. When I close the windows and make another plot, I get the plot and all previous plot-windows plus a black windows.

---

I am on Linux Kubuntu 14.4 (yes, it is old, but this should not matter here). I am running my code from a Python Console in PyCharm 2019.2.3 using the conda environment in the background.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Where do you run the code? CMD/Terminal or some IDE?

Comment: @eyllanesc: From a Python Console in PyCharm which uses the conda backend.